# IConfigurationDbContext returning missing columns

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to search for valid clients in on my Identity server.  Its currently runnning identityserver4.

**My code:**

```
    // GET api/developerconsole/{clientId}
    [HttpGet("{clientId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = _configurationDbContext.Clients.Find(1);  // Fails here
            return Ok(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }

    }
```

**The error**

```
Invalid column name 'BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired'.
Invalid column name 'BackChannelLogoutUri'.
Invalid column name 'ClientClaimsPrefix'.
Invalid column name 'ConsentLifetime'.
Invalid column name 'Description'.
Invalid column name 'FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired'.
Invalid column name 'FrontChannelLogoutUri'.
Invalid column name 'PairWiseSubjectSalt'.
```

**ConfigurationDbContext injection**

```
 // IDS
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaIdentityConnection")));
```

I don't understand why it would be missing columns

**Update:**

As suggested in comments I ran

> dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema

It resulted in the following error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet
>   More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

Note:

> dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema -c ConfigurationDbContext

No parameterless constructor was found on 'ConfigurationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ConfigurationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ConfigurationDbContext'.

Update 2:

It appears that the code in the project should support the migration its using this  [Using EntityFramework Core for configuration and operational data](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html)

The only difference i can see is that we request our user data from another database

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(builder =>builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionToUserDB")));
```

Update :

I tried creating a idbcontextfactory

```
 public class ConfigurationFactory : IDbContextFactory<ConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public ConfigurationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var connectionString = "server=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Xena.Identity2.0;Integrated Security=true";
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Xena.IdentityServer"));
        return new ConfigurationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());

    }
}
```

This allowed me to

> dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema -c ConfigurationDbContext
>
> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet
>   Executed DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
>   Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
>   Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>   FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>   ORDER BY [MigrationId];
>   Applying migration '20171201112112_updatedIdentityServer4Schema'.
>   Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
>   VALUES (N'20171201112112_updatedIdentityServer4Schema', N'1.1.2');
>   Done.

after which i did an update.   But the new columns have not appeared in my database.

Comment: Did you use it previously and now it is not working or it is not working from the scratch?

Comment: The identity server has been running for a while this is a new API I am creating.   my research says that there must be some changes to the identity server 4 model that I don't have in my database but I have been unable to figure out how to add them.

Comment: Have you added the migrations required to set up Identity Server 4? If you're using EF Core, then it's a case of running `dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema` against the correct project in your solution. This will add the migration necessary, then you'll need to apply the migration `dotnet ef database update` is along the right lines.

Comment: @JamieTaylor i rescently took over this project so i am not exactly sure what its designed to do. I ran the command you suggested check the update comment for the errors.  I am going to try and Google them myself thanks for the idea.

Comment: `dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema -c ConfigurationDbContext`

Comment: @serpent5 yeah i tried that :)  No parameterless constructor was found on 'ConfigurationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ConfigurationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory<ConfigurationDbContext>' in the same assembly as 'ConfigurationDbContext'.

Comment: Do you have your own `ConfigurationDbContext` class or is it just the IdentityServer provided version? I have a similar project that works fine with  that command. Also, was the project previously running using an RC version of IS4 and then updated to RTM?

Comment: The IdentityServer provided version.  I have spent the llast hour trying to figuer how to do this IDbContextFactory<ConfigurationDbContext>

Comment: You seem to be injecting a lot of services manually that should be taken care of for you. There might be some confusion in that. Try removing what you've commented as `// IDS` and re-running the EF migration command. The code from your link (and what I use) sets up the connection-string with `AddConfigurationStore`.

Comment: without the stuff in // Ids nothing will run i need access to the data in both databases.   Unfortunately this was created with the users in a different database from the Identity server client stuff.

Comment: The only difference that should make is that your connection-strings would be different. I don't think the separation of the data is contributing to your issues here. I can't try and help any further as there is not enough information to try and diagnose this further. Good luck.

Comment: Let me know what information you need I can give you what ever you like.  If you run the first code i posted you can test it so there is enough information here to test to recreate the problem its not something that should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the full Identity server project has been upgraded to 2.0.  and builds there have been some breaking changes in IdentityServer4 2.0

I added the following

```
public class ConfigurationFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ConfigurationDbContext>
    {
        public ConfigurationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Xena.Identity2.0;Integrated Security=true";
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Xena.IdentityServer"));
            return new ConfigurationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
        }
    }

public class PersistedGrantDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<PersistedGrantDbContext>
    {
        public PersistedGrantDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Xena.Identity2.0;Integrated Security=true";
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Xena.IdentityServer"));
            return new PersistedGrantDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, new OperationalStoreOptions());
        }
    }
```

Then i was able to preform

```
dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema -c ConfigurationDbContext
dotnet ef database update -c ConfigurationDbContext
dotnet ef migrations add updatedIdentityServer4Schema -c 
PersistedGrantDbContext
dotnet ef database update -c PersistedGrantDbContext
```

To update to the newest version of the database for IdentityServer4.  I recommend fixing the above code to work with the config files which it doesn't do currently.

Comment: Is it necessary to use certificate in identity server 4 because i am getting this error :Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:33132/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.